# Can I use a class instead of a function with map in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

According to the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), the `map` function "applies *function* to every item of *iterable* and returns a list of the results". I've noticed that it also works for classes, e.g. `map(MyClass, get_iterable())` and returns a list of the class instances.
Is this correct usage of `map`?

Answer (score 5):

The docs actually say “Apply *function* to every item of iterable” where *function* is a reference to the parameter name. So yes, `map` can be used with any callable; and all types are callable (in that they will create an object of that type).

Comment: With different words, the docs say "map(banana, iterable, ...)
Apply *banana* to every item of *iterable* and return a list of the results"

Comment: @planetp Is there a reason why you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 3):

`map` expects a callable. If an object is a callable, that works too:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __call__(self, foo):
        return foo

print map(Foo(), [1,2,3])
```

Comment: Every `type` is a callable

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
>>> map(str, [1,2,3])
['1', '2', '3']
```

the doc refers to `function` as the *name* of the argument. Its type is irrelevant - it should only be callable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, python is duck-typed, so if something can be called (such as the MyClass constructor) on the iterable, then it will return no error (and it will be valid).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. in your example, you are actually mapping the constructor of the class to the list of item.